# Is it true that a book kept on the table is accelerating with $9.8 m/s^2$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Is it true that a book kept on the table is continuously accelerating with 9.8 m/s^2 downwards?
The table is stopping it from falling because if the table hadn't been there without applying force, the book would have fallen down?
Can this be extended to other phenomena and is this, in other words, confirming the fact that you need acceleration to exert the force on a surface because f = ma?
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Is the table accelerating?

Comment: In classical mechanics, no. In general relativity, yes.

Comment: no, table is at rest

Answer (score 6):

The answer is no, if the table is at rest.

It is true that the gravity is pulling the book but the table is providing the book a ***normal force*** of equal magnitude as that of the book's weight in the upward direction.

The book exerts normal force on the table and in turn the table exerts an equal normal force to the book in the upward direction (in accordance with Newton's third law). The normal force exerted by the table on the book cancels out the weight of the book.

[image]

Thus, the net force on the book in the vertical direction is $0$, which implies the net acceleration is $0$.

***Additional info :***

The book pushes the table by the normal force, not by the gravitational force.

Comment: You wrote if the table is at rest to be certain that centripetal acceleration cause of rotation is ignored . Right ?

Comment: The question doesn't specify any circular motion. This question is a primitive Newtonian mechanics question. Therefore, the earth is assumed to be at rest and usually the reference frame for most such questions. What i had in mind was to make sure that the table isn't accelerating wrt the earth. There may some situations where the table may be freely falling, or be stationary wrt to a accelerating elevator. My motive was to exclude these situation where the book may be at rest wrt to the table, while the table accelerates with acceleration either equal or not equal to $g$.

Comment: Ok. I took that the table is not falling or any types of those accelerations. And we just need to ignore the rotation of earth. Anyways both are correct ! Btw I'll ping you at the chat about the chemistry questions as soon as possible...

Answer (score 3):

When the book is kept on the table,from the frame of reference of the observer standing near the table the forces acting on the book are the gravitational force acting downward due to earth and normal reaction acting upwards due to the table.These two forces are equal and opposite to each other and hence the net force acting on the book is zero.Since the net force is zero,from Newton's second law(F=ma) the acceleration of the book is zero and it is practically at rest.

Comment: ok, but what about the fact that a = f/m, we have the force acting on an object and it has mass then why isn't it accelerating?

Comment: There is also a reaction force from the table acting on the book.  Net force is zero. Acceleration is zero.

Comment: In a=f/m f is not just "the force" acting on the book it is the "net force",which is zero and hence the acceleration is zero.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's true that the book is continuously accelerating *upwards* at $g$. Before I go further, take heed that this answer does *not* contradict the other answers that say the book is not accelerating - that its weight is balanced by the table-to-book reaction force. The other answers that say this are altogether and precisely correct from a Newtonian physics perspective, and, if you're studying Newtonian physics or mechanics, this is the answer you should "accept".

However, from a (slightly - 100+ years old) more modern perspective, the book is indeed being accelerated, but *upwards*, rather than downwards. In General Relativity, one determines an inertial frame to be any frame that, *relative to the Earth's surface* is accelerating downwards at $g$ at the Earth's surface. Objects freefalling in this way are following the spacetime geodesics that are defined by the metric that is the solution of the Einstein field equations in this case (the spacetime around the Earth is described, to an excellent approximation, by the so-called Schwarzschild metric). Newton's second law then takes the form that anything accelerating at acceleration $\vec{a}$ relative to such an inertial frame requires a force $m\,\vec{a}$ to make it deviate from geodesic motion. In this case, this force comes from the table as the book "tries" to follow geodesics in spacetime, but cannot pass through the table - for reasons that are owing to solid state physics (interactions between solid matter things like books and tables) and are nothing really to do with relativity or gravity. So the table pushes back to make the book deviate from general relativistic inertial motion. There is *only* the reaction force; there is no weight in a general relativistic perspective, and the reaction force accelerates the book steadily upwards at $g$. It so happens that such an accelerated frame is stationary relative to the Earth's surface. This is a steady state situation that arises from the solid state physics of all the stuff that makes up the Earth.

Comment: Hopefully this answer won't leave the OP totally confused but will instead give them a taste for the wonderfulness of GR. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I was a little hesitant, because the OP is clearly struggling with Newtonian mechanics - hopefully the first paragraph is a good enough caveat. Do you think the answer should be left here? I guess any "damage" has already been done, though!

Comment: I think this answer should stay. It may introduce future readers to GR. And maybe the OP is having troubles with Newtonian because their physics intuition is more attuned to GR...

Answer (score 1):

No, it's true that the book is on a gravitational field and a force is acting on it, but the table is making an equal force but in the opposite direction. According to the Newton's second law the resultant force is the mass of the book multiplied by its acceleration, so if the resultant force (the sum of the gravitational force and the force that the table makes in the book) is 0 the acceleration is 0. Acceleration is just the change of velocity and the book on the table is not changing its velocity so it's not been acelerated.

Comment: In the first line, you might want to be specific about the 'force' (namely, that it is the normal force on book by the table, and not the total force)

Comment: The first force which I talk about is the gravitational force, because the book is on a gravitational field and if there wasn't a table the book would be accelerated with 9 m/s^2. As there's a table, that gravitational force is contrarrested with the normal force that the table makes on the book, which is equal and opposite.